# Beamer: How to format both frametitle and framesubtitle

Tags: beamer, formatting

I wish to customize the appearance of both my `frametitle` and `framesubtitle`. However when I try to do so, only the `frametitle` is rendered. This is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[20pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{white}\textbf{\tiny\insertframetitle}}
\setbeamertemplate{framesubtitle}{\color{white}\tiny\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello world}{Hello world subtitle}
\begin{equation*}
h_\alpha = \left\| \partial_\alpha \vec{r} \right\|
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the only the title is rendered. Why is that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Also, you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, there's no `framesubtitle` template, but you have the possibility to set an independent color and font for the `framesubtitle` by using

```
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{<your specification>}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{<your specification>}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[20pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}

\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\normalfont\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello world}{Hello world subtitle}
\begin{equation*}
h_\alpha = \left\| \partial_\alpha \vec{r} \right\|
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that since you are changing only color and font attributes for the `frametitle`, you can set those attributes also using the color and font for `frametitle` (as I did in my example code), instead of using the `frametitle` template which would make more sense for major changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you're not telling `beamer` to typeset the `framesubtitle`. I don't think the `framesubtitle` is a template you can set... The following works for me:

```
\documentclass[20pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\textbf{\insertframetitle}\\\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello world}
\begin{equation*}
h_\alpha = \left\| \partial_\alpha \vec{r} \right\|
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```